# Writing http response from an second goroutine

Tags: go, spotify

I've been playing around with the spotify api and came to an Problem. `context.Context` gets used and therefore the functions just "randomly" execute. The OAuth function should check if the Code is invalid but If I don't do this with an channel the last part of the code gets executed directly without even the first/second function finishing. Because of that I made an second goroutine that checks if the channel is received and then write an response. But now I get this error `http: wrote more than the declared Content-Length` how can I correct the Content-Lenght? Why is context even used?

My Code:

```
// Wrapper: github.com/zmb3/spotify/v2

func WriteResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, h chan *spotify.Client) {

    client := <-h

    user, err := client.CurrentUser(context.Background())
    fmt.Println(user.User.DisplayName)
    if err != nil {
        _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, "Couldn't get user sorry :(")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Logged in as %s!", user.User.DisplayName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

func OAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ch := make(chan *spotify.Client)

    tok, err := auth.Token(r.Context(), state, r)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(503)
        _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, "Couldn't get token sorry :(")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }

    if st := r.FormValue("state"); st != state {
        http.NotFound(w,r)
        log.Fatalf("State mismatch: %s != %s\n", st, state)
    }

    go WriteResponse(w, ch)
    client := spotify.New(auth.Client(r.Context(), tok))

    ch <- client
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return..

```
if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(503)
        _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, "Couldn't get token sorry :(")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        // here
        return
    }
```